# Letting user pass values for an animation

Tags: jquery, animation

hi new to jquery and i am trying to let a user put in the values that would effect animation. (moving it up or down)this is what i have so far seems i cant get it to pass the values to get it to animate, anyhelp would be great.

html

```
<select id="selectBox">
<option selected="selected" class="selectBox" value="top">Top </option>
<option class="selectBox" value="bottom">Bottom </option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="value" />
<input id="button" name="button" value="Animate" type="button"> 

<div class="box"style="height:100px; width:300px; padding: 35px; margin:50px auto; 
border:30px solid #000;">
```

​javascript/jquery

```
< script type = "text/javascript" >

$("#button").click(function() {
var boxType = $('#selectBox').val();
var value = $('#value').val();

console.log(boxType + " " + value);

if (boxType == "top") {
    $(".box").stop().animate({
        marginTop: $('input').val('changed input value');
    }, 1000);
}
if (boxType == "bottom") {
    console.log("marginBottom")
    $(".box").stop().animate({
        marginBottom: $('input').val('changed input value');
    }, 1000);
}
}); < /script>​

here it is on JSFIDDLE
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X5Dd4/

Comment: Try to write the question simple and precise!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the semicolons at the end of these two lines:

```
marginTop: $('input').val('changed input value');
...
marginTop: $('input').val('changed input value');
```

...because they're invalid inside object literals. But also calling `.val()` to *set* the values of the input doesn't make sense in those lines. Just use the `value` variable that you set towards the beginning of your code that already holds what the user entered.

Something like this:

```
if (boxType == "top") {
    $(".box").stop().animate({
        marginTop: value
    }, 1000);
}
if (boxType == "bottom") {
    console.log("marginBottom")
    $(".box").stop().animate({
        marginBottom: value 
    }, 1000);
}
```

And in your fiddle you need to remove the `<script>` and `</script>` tags from inside the JS window - the code you show there is the body of an `onload` handler.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/X5Dd4/1/

Note that animating the margin bottom isn't very exciting in the fiddle since it just pushes down whatever is below the box and there is nothing below it.

(Also, given that your code has a `console.log()` statement in it, are you not looking at your console? When I went to your fiddle the semicolon error and the `<script>` tag problem were both reported in the console.)